# Instagram API: How to know a media's privacy level?

Tags: instagram, privacy

I'm syncing a bunch of media from instagram. Some show up with thumbnails that say 403 forbidden along with this response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error>
    <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
    <Message>Access Denied</Message>
    <RequestId>*********</RequestId>
    <HostId>*********</HostId>
</Error>
```

I have no problem with this, but I would like to simply skip these photos as I'm doing my sync. Is there anything in the media response I can use to detect the privacy level of the photos?

Thanks!

Comment: I just realized I think I posted twice! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21711879/querying-tags-tag-name-media-recent-endpoint-how-to-avoid-private-photos But I think there might be 2 issues at hand here. One being privacy or NSFW flags, and the other being image URLs changing in time.

Comment: Ok these are actually deleted photos, confirmed. I'll close my questions and rewrite a clearer question!